# i need help installing some libraries

Tags: 22.04, libraries, shared-library, arm64

I'm trying to install polymc on my Orange Pi 5 Plus with box86 and box64. I'm kind of new at this, and it's saying it's missing these libraries.

```
Error loading needed lib libQt6Charts.so.6
Error loading needed lib libQt6Widgets.so.6
Error loading needed lib libQt6Network.so.6
Error loading needed lib libQt6Core5Compat.so.6
Error loading needed lib libQt6Gui.so.6
Error loading needed lib libQt6Core.so.6
```

Comment: i forgot to include libQt6Xml.so.6

Comment: As packages are built for a specific release, and we don't know your OS/release, we can only provide *generic* answers that may or may not work on your *unstated* system (*given we can't tailor answers for an OS/release when we don't know it*)

Comment: im using ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 1):

Update your package information:

```
sudo apt update
```

Upgrade your system to current packages:

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

Install apt-file

```
sudo apt install apt-file
```

Update the apt-file data:

```
apt-file update
```

Then you may use the apt-file search to find the package of a file (library in your case)

```
apt-file search libQt6Charts.so.6
```

With the packages identified, just install them:

```
sudo apt install <insert your list of packages>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the relevant package names when you search within the contents of packages with the library names at https://packages.ubuntu.com/.

```
sudo apt install libqt6charts6 libqt6widgets6 libQt6network6 libqt6core5compat6 libqt6gui6 libqt6core6 libqt6xml6
```

Comment: still didnt work

Comment: What was the error message? Unless you exactly tell us what the error is, we cannot do anything

Comment: [link] (https://github.com/Eternal587/Eternal587.github.io/blob/main/terminallog.txt)

Comment: Can you also try `sudo apt install qt6-base-dev`?